# Write multiple Arrays, of various sizes, into a text file

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following issue:

I need to write a given number of Arrays, which all have the same number of rows, but a different number of columns into a text file. Is there another way other than checking for each array, which dimesnion it has and then writing each entry into the text file?

I tried something like this:

```
def WriteResultToTxt(X,Y):

    f = open('Test.txt','w')
    Z = zip(X,Y)
    np.savetxt(f,Z)
    f.close
```

and when I try this:

```
x = np.arange(0,200,1).reshape((100,2))
y = np.arange(0,50,0.5).reshape((100,1))
WriteResultToTxt(x,y)
```

I get an 'tuple index out of range' error

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you're objective? How does the resulting TXT should look like?

Comment: basicly like an excel sheet. Each array should be in a column and each column seperated by a tab or something like that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Use numpy concatenate to join the arrays into one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,200,1).reshape((100,2))
y = np.arange(0,50,0.5).reshape((100,1))
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x), pd.DataFrame(y)], axis=1).to_csv('foo.csv')
```

First concatenate the two arrays and then export to CSV. By specifying `axis=1` the concatenation would be column-wise; one next to the other and not row-wise.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Could you explain what the 'axis=1' is used for?

Comment: What if I have not only x and y but lets say 20 such arrays. Is there an elegant way to concatinate them?

Comment: The argument of `concat` is a list, you can provide it with a list of arrays. If they have different number of rows, you might have to be a little careful